# How can a global function call a specific function in a class?

Tags: c++, vector, global

I have a global function and a class containing few member functions as per below:

Function Vert() is printing blank on console.

While debugging I found that the values at Vertice1[i] is null so may be its coming blank on the console. But dispFileName does contain the values.

Am I passing the values correctly to the vector?

//Vector Definition:

Comment: Are you getting any errors or other problems?  What?

Comment: Are you not getting a warning about redefining the "v" variable?

Comment: no am not getting errors... Its just not printing anything from the vector on console. After debugging I feel the vector has been formed correctly, but it contains no value. Am I passing the values correctly to the vector?

Comment: no am not getting warning about redfinition of v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first `for` loop ends, you've got a vector of pointers to Vertex objects. But the actual Vertex objects have **gone out of scope**, since they're local to the first `for` loop. So **your pointers are invalid at that point**, and you're getting random results (in this case, empty strings).

Here I'm assuming that `Graph<T, U>::Vertice1` is a `std::vector<Vertex<T, U>*>` rather than something involving smart pointers.

The simplest solution is to make the vector contain Vertex objects, rather than pointers to Vertex objects.

Comment: Yes here is the definition of my Vertice1 vector:                         std::vector<project3::Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>*> Vertice1;

Comment: I tried removing the pointer, but its giving me an error while printing - IntelliSense: expression must have pointer type

Comment: I am getting that error on "std::cout << (g1.Vertice1[i]) -> Vert()<<endl;" inside 2nd for loop.

Comment: @tech_learning: Do you know what the arrow operator "->" means in C++?

Comment: As per whatever knowledge I have on this it only points to Vert() and display the output of Vert()... I am learning and new to templates and vectors so not sure though.

Comment: But yes, you are correct. The Vertex objects are going out of scope and hence there is no output when 2nd for loop gets executed. If I try to in 1st for loop... there is some output on console.

Comment: @tech_learning: The `->` operator doesn't *point* to Vert(). Also, it doesn't display the output of Vert() - `std::cout` is what displays the output. The `->` operator in this context means "call Vert() on the object *pointed-to* by `g1.Vertice1[i]`". So `g1.Vertice1[i]` needs to be a pointer. If it's not a pointer, then you can't use the `->` operator; the dot operator **"."** is for that. I think you need to find a better book/tutorial if yours doesn't mention that :)

Comment: And i made the required changes and getting the output. Thanks a lot for the quick help... else I would have kept on looking at the code searching for the issue. Also, would be thankful to you again, if you could let me know the exact use of operator ->.